# How to get EditText value from layout to MainPage.xaml

Tags: android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to get the value from an EditText that i have in my Android layout to a method that i have on the MainPage.xaml.cs and idk how.

Thanks in advance

This would be my android layout:
[AndroidLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUlgK.png)

and this would be the code that I have in MainPage.xaml, those are the varibles that I need to fill out with the values from the EditText

```
 private async void GuardarEstudiante_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var Nombre;
        var Apellidos;
        var FechaNacimiento;
        var Enfermedades;
        var Telefono;
        var Correo;        
    }
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: You can use Event Action (same like messegeCenter), if you could provide the code then we can try to give the solution.

Comment: Are you using Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.Forms? Please post the relevant code

Comment: Done guys, i just edited it, thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be using the MessagingCenter API

When you check the [Microsoft documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center#passing-an-argument) it says:

> To pass an argument with the message, specify the argument Type in the Subscribe generic arguments and in the Action signature.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, string> (this, "Hi", (sender, arg) => {
// do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent
// using the 'arg' parameter which is a string
});
```

> To send the message with argument, include the Type generic parameter and the value of the argument in the Send method call.

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, string> (this, "Hi", "John");
```

This simple example uses a string argument but any C# object can be passed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new complex object if you don't have one that represents the "student information"

In the click event it seems you may be navigating ?

If so then simply pass it into the constructor of the next view ... it really is that simple my friend